# Proof check regarding complete space with seminorm

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, complete-spaces

I just came across a simple Functional Analysis exercise which I just dont know if I correctly solved. The problem states:

Consider the space $C(\mathbb{R}):=\{f: \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}; f$ continuous$\}$ equipped with the seminorm:

$$
p_{j}(f)=\sup \{|f(x)| ;|x| \leq j\}, \quad j \in \mathbb{N}
$$

Prove that:

**1.** Let $f_{n} \in C(\mathbb{R}), n \in \mathbb{N}$, be defined by $f_{n}(x)=x-n+|x-n|, x \in \mathbb{R}$. Show that $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} f_{n}=0$.

**2.** Show that $C(\mathbb{R})$ is a complete metric space.

**Regarding Completeness**

Let $\left(f_{n}\right)_{n}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $C(\mathbb{R})$. Now, noting that:

$$
H=\left\{\left|f_{n}(x)-f_{m}(x)\right| ;|x| \leqslant j\right\} \subseteq G \doteq\left\{\left|f_{n}(x)-f_{m}(x)\right|x \in \mathbb{R}\right\}
$$

We conclude that $\sup H \leq \sup G$. Noting that $\sup G$ is precisely the $\sup$ norm, means we have:
$$
0 \leq p_{j}\left(f_{n}-f_{m}\right) \leqslant\left\|f_{n}-f_{m}\right\|_{\infty}
$$

Since $C(\mathbb{R})$ is complete with respect to the sup norm, we have that our initial Cauchy sequence $\left(f_{n}\right)_{n}$ converges to a function $f$, which should be continuous as well, with respect to the $\sup$ norm. This implies that there exists $n_{0}$ such that for $n, m > n_{0}$, we have that $\left\|f_{n}-f_{m}\right\|_{\infty} < \epsilon$, which implies:

$$
0 \leq p_{j}\left(f_{n}-f_{m}\right) \leqslant\left\|f_{n}-f_{m}\right\|_{\infty} < \epsilon
$$

Consequently, $p_{j}\left(f_{n}-f_{m}\right)$ is a Cauchy sequence which converges to $f$ the same continuous function, turning our initial space equipped with the seminorm $p_{j}$ complete.

**Regarding the limit $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} f_{n}=0$**:

We want to show that, given $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $n_{0}$ such that for $n > n_{0} \implies p_{j}(f_{n}, 0) < \epsilon$. Since $\mathbb{N}$ is unbounded, there exists $N$ such that for every $n > N$, the difference $|x-n| = n-x$. This implies that:

$$
\begin{aligned}
p_{j}(f_{n}, 0) & \doteq \sup \{|x-n+|x-n|| ;|x| \leqslant j\}=\\
&=\sup \{|0| ;|x| \leqslant j \mid=0<\varepsilon
\end{aligned}
$$

which proves that $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} f_{n}=0$ with respect to the seminorm $p_{j}$.

**Questions:**

1. Are the arguments ok for each of the questions? If no, what is missing? Is it well written?

Thanks in advance, Lucas

Comment: In your question, you should show every Cauchy sequence w.r.t. $p_j$ is convergent in $p_j$ seminorm. But $p_j$-Cauchy sequence might not be a sup-Cauchy sequence(sup over the whole space).

Comment: Can you explain this in further detail? I did not get it. It just seems to me that the inequality i wrote took care of this issue

Comment: The issue is that, it might be possible that $p_j(f_n - f_m) < \epsilon < \|f_n-f_m\|_{\infty}$ for $n, m$ large, because you should only assume $\{f_n\}$ is $p_j$-Cauchy.

Comment: But since the space of continuous functions with the sup norm is complete, doesn't one get the inequality I wrote?

Comment: No. You're checking the completeness of the seminorms, NOT the completeness for the sup norm. So you assume that you have a Cauchy sequence $\{f_n\}$ in $p_j$ norm, then your goal is to prove $\{f_n\}$ has a limit in $p_j$ norm. However, $\{f_n\}$ might NOT be Cauchy in sup norm.

Comment: Got it, do you know how to finish the argument properly? Also, what did you think of the reasoning behind proving the limit of $f_{n} = 0$?

Comment: It's quite similar to the argument showing the completeness w.r.t. the sup norm. Try to take a look at that. The argument showing $f_n \to 0$ is fine, but you need to note that your $N$ is s.t. $|x-n| = n-x$ for $|x| \leq j$ whenever $n > N$ (i.e., this $N$ is independent of $x$), but this is always achievable for fixed $j$.